# how to read data connection string and multiple sql commands from one text file and save output in output.txt in c#

Tags: c#

I have an input.txt file and its first line is the database connection string(Access DB), and proceed with multiple sql commands.

I have to create a program that reads database connection string from this input.txt file makes connection and then read one by one sql commands from this input.txt and execute individually, save results of all transactions in an output.txt file.

I succeeded in making a connection, but I don't know how to do the rest of the work.

my code is:

```
{
    private static int i;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Making connection to Access database via input.txt
        string fileLoc = @"C:\\input.txt";
       // reading input.txt
        String pro;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
        {
            String line = sr.ReadLine();
            pro = line;
        }
        OleDbConnection con = null;
        try
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection(pro);
            con.Open();

            // trying new one
            String command;
            using (StreamReader csr = new StreamReader(@"C:\\commands.txt"))
            {
                String line = csr.ReadLine();
                pro = line;
            }
            OleDbConnection cCon = null;



            // Execute SQL Commands 
            OleDbCommand comm = con.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandText = pro;

            //Read and process data rows
            IDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            object[] dataRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            string[] write = {"Maria", " Hafeez"};
            //string m = "      | {0} ";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int cols = reader.GetValues(dataRow);
                for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                {

                    Console.Write("      | {0} ", dataRow[i]);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
                //write = dataRow[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
            string path =@"C:\\output.txt";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                //output in output.txt
                File.WriteAllLines(path, write);
            }
            //Release resources and close connection   
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (con != null)
                    // ----- close connection 
                    con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Would this be some kind of homework?

Comment: yes, it is an assignment

Answer (score 0):

First, this is "wrong", because it will CLOSE the file, before getting to the point where you can iterate through it.

```
        String command;
        using (StreamReader csr = new StreamReader(@"C:\\commands.txt"))
        {
            String line = csr.ReadLine();
            pro = line;
        }
```

You have to maintain the file OPEN during the process, or read all lines and store on a List for example.

In the first case (file still open), you can do like this: you have to "iterate" through the lines of the file.

```
// Making connection to Access database via input.txt
string fileLoc = @"C:\\input.txt";
// reading input.txt
String pro;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
{
    String line = sr.ReadLine();
    pro = line;

    OleDbConnection con = null;

    con = new OleDbConnection(pro);
    con.Open();

    string line;
    while((line = csr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Execute SQL Commands 
        OleDbCommand comm = con.CreateCommand();
        comm.Connection = con;
        comm.CommandText = line; //<<= this to get the actual line in the file

        //Read and process data rows
        IDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        object[] dataRow = new object[reader.FieldCount];
        string[] write = {"Maria", " Hafeez"};
        //string m = "      | {0} ";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int cols = reader.GetValues(dataRow);
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {

                Console.Write("      | {0} ", dataRow[i]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            //write = dataRow[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        string path =@"C:\\output.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            //output in output.txt
            File.WriteAllLines(path, write);
        }
        //Release resources and close connection   
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

I think this is enough, no? The rest you can figure out (try catch blocks, closing the connecction, etc)

Comment: I get your point but this is not enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Μαρια, and what's the problem? What are you still missing?

Comment: what I am doing is taking connection string from input.txt and sql command from commands.txt, in real there is a file named input.txt and its first line is conn string and preceding multiple DML queries, I've to pick fisrt line built a database conn and them pick one by one query, execute it and save in output.txt

Comment: @Μαρια, I know the problem. You stated it on your question. I would like to understand what you didn't understood on my answer. You said it is not enough. So, what you didn't understood?